# MFC - Problem using CSettingStore to open registry key

Tags: mfc

I would like to check if .NET 3.5 Framework is installed by reading the "Install" value of the key "Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v3.5". I am very happy to find out that there is an MFC class CSettingStore that can do the job easily but I found out the CSettingStore.Open always return false.

The code is as follow:

```
bool bOpen = reg.Open(_T("Software\\Microsoft\\NET Framework Setup\\NDP\\v3.5"));
if (bOpen && reg.Read (_T("Install"), dwInstall))
{
    return dwInstall == 1;
}
```

In this case, reg.Open always return false.

Anything wrong with the code?

Comment: Could you show how do you construct the `reg` object?

Comment: CSettingsStore reg (FALSE, TRUE);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982796.aspx I read:

```
<quote>
```

The meaning of `bAdmin` is reversed
Actually, if `bAdmin` is true, the key is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` and, if it's false, the key is `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`. You can see this for yourself in `afxsettingsstore.cpp`:

```
CSettingsStore::CSettingsStore(BOOL bAdmin, BOOL bReadOnly) :
m_bReadOnly(bReadOnly), m_bAdmin(bAdmin), m_dwUserData(0)
{
m_reg.m_hKey = bAdmin ? HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE : HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
}

</quote>
```

So it looks like a documentation bug. Does `CSettingsStore reg (TRUE, TRUE);` work better?

Comment: Thank yo so much. Exactly the documentation bug. I use CSettingsStore reg (TRUE, TRUE) now and it works.